# iOS appClip status Received?

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I've just finished setup my advanced App Clip Experiences .

i am not sure if i need to wait or is there anything else i should do , since the App Clip status is lighted green with status `Received` .

also couldn't find any useful information about the App Clip status in apple documentation, dose anyone has experience with App Clip can share the status of live App Clip and if require additional information after the `Received` status .

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Mines says "1 Valid Domain," but it's not an advanced experience. There really is barely any documentation. I just released the app clip (without announcing it), then checked if it worked. It worked.

Comment: @aheze , its worked for me too but only me i've sent the link for my friends its not working for them , i think because i've added my apple id as appcclip tester , can you share the status of your appclip what dose it say ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it just says "Validated" ([screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202021-06-20%20at%2010.52.50%20PM.png))

Comment: However my app clip is just a basic experience, not advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well , for some reason in the first 5 days me and my colleagues couldn't open app clip from our safari app , after that the banner starts to show up into our website in every safari 14+ iOS version , i believe its caching issue with apple servers on safari .

Answer (score 1):

The build that hosts your App Clip needs to have gone through a full cycle of App Review, and it needs to be released to the App Store before anyone can use the App Clip you submitted.

App Store Connect's UI is confusing in this respect. It says "received", but unless the binary is fully released, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

2023 Aug update: we have an app that has passed review and is live in the App Store, but the Advanced App Clip Experiences are still in "Received" status.  While waiting for App Store Support to respond, we started poking around and noticed the Filter button.

[image: Advanced App Clip Experiences header]

Clicking on that, we noticed the Status drop down, but it only had the Received status in it, because it only populates with actual statuses of your Experiences (not all possible statuses).

[image: Filter dialog with Status]

But if you inspect the page, you can find what the possible other statuses are (in addition to "RECEIVED"):

```
<input name="status" value="["CREATE_SUBMITTED","UPDATE_SUBMITTED","IN_REVIEW","PUBLISHED","APP_TRANSFER_UPDATE","APP_TRANSFER_DELETE"]" class="">
```

So I think it has to show "Published" before your Experience is fully live.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the Apple reviewer just forgot to publish the App Clip after accepting the main app.